# Display custom avatar image during membership plan activated

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, gravatar

I am using [WooCommerce Memberships by SkyVerge](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-memberships/)
for a membership plan, the issue is, when users buy a membership plz their avatar image should be changed to my custom image URL and when their membership gets expires their avatar will get back to normal

ref:https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-memberships-function-reference/

```
add_filter('woocommerce-memberships', 'wpb_new_gravatar', 1);

$memberships = wc_memberships_get_user_active_memberships($user_id);

if ($user === $memberships) {

    function wpb_new_gravatar($avatar_defaults) {
        $myavatar = 'https://buysnd.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Circle_Design_Membership_Level_GOLD.webp';
        $avatar_defaults[$myavatar] = "Default Gravatar";
        return $avatar_defaults;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check doc for howto use hooks, for this specific case, you can use the hook [pre_get_avatar](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_avatar/)

```
add_filter('pre_get_avatar', 'custom_gravatar', 10, 3);

function custom_gravatar($avatar, $id_or_email, $args) {
    $uid = get_current_user_id();
    if ($uid && wc_memberships_get_user_active_memberships($uid)) {
        $avatar = "<img src='https://buysnd.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Circle_Design_Membership_Level_GOLD.webp'/>";
    }
    return $avatar;
}
```

Comment: hi, can u plz help me one more time, I want both as conditional if a user is a member then they're Avatar is different and when he is not a member then different?

Comment: Custom Default Gravatar For Members

`add_filter('pre_get_avatar', 'custom_gravatar', 1, 3);
function custom_gravatar($avatar, $id_or_email, $args) {
    $uid = get_current_user_id();
    if ($uid && wc_memberships_get_user_active_memberships($uid)) {
        $avatar = "<img src='https://staranddaisy.in/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Circle_Design_Membership_Level_GOLD.webp'/>";
    }
    return $avatar;
}`

Comment: Default Gravatar For All Users
`add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'wpb_new_gravatar' );
function wpb_new_gravatar ($avatar_defaults) {
$myavatar = 'http://staranddaisy.in/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/smily_icon_avatar-1.png';
$avatar_defaults[$myavatar] = "Default Gravatar";
return $avatar_defaults;}`